# How to set key for array item?

Tags: javascript

I would like to use jquery post:

```
var CONST_KEY = 'key';
var CONST_VALUE = 'value';

$.post('/', {CONST_KEY: "'" + CONST_VALUE + "'" }, function(){
//.....
});
```

But in this case server gets:

> CONST_KEY = value

Why CONST_KEY is sending as a variable name but not as a 'value'?

Comment: Note that what you have there is an object, not an array.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're wrapping the value in quotes as part of the POST string? There shouldn't be a need to.

Comment: It's for some module and it is for CSRF using. Each cms could have CSRF-key and CSRF-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You unfortunately can't do it like that. Try this...

```
var obj = {};

obj[CONST_KEY] = "'" + CONST_VALUE + "'";
```

JavaScript treats unquoted key names as strings, and doesn't resolve them to variable lookups. However, if they look like a non-valid string name, they can be resolved, e.g. `0x100` resolves to `256`.

Recently, you can also use reserved words in JavaScript as bare keys, such as `delete` and `class`.